# Create a synthesis map ( e.g. climatic vulnerability) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, maps

My final goal is to create a synthesis map of climatic vulnerabilities composed by different thematic variable with different weights.

I would like to ask for support for the following issues:

1. For each thematic map  I am creating a vector map with different classes. How to convert this vector map to a raster map, keeping the classification?
2. The second step would be to calculate a raster map as result of a weighted sum of the thematic maps previously generated. How can I do this in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange Vera! Please note that the format of this website requires one focused question per thread. You can find more information about asking questions in our [faq].   Also it might be interesting to know if you would be open to a vector-only solution as well.